# The output of this PHP statement

Tags: php, echo

The output of this PHP statement is:

```
$a = 'a'; $b = 'b';

echo isset($c) ? $a.$b.$c : ($c = 'c').'d';
```

it shows 'cd', but one question here is:

why `($c = 'c')` is `'c'`??

What is the order of execution of this statement? Is that simmilar to: `echo ($c = 'c').'d';` ?

Comment: What else would you expect `($c = 'c')` to be?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php
first `(...)` then `.` . the result of `($c = 'c')` is $c (which equals now 'c')

Comment: Since you assigned `'c'` to `$c`

Comment: `($c = 'c')` is an assignment of the value `c` to `$c`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using a ternary operator ? which is similar to if... else statement.
because the variable $c is not set it executes `($c = 'c').'d'` then it asigns the value 'c' to the `$c` variable and ( because the assignment is done in a expression) `($c = 'c')` is parsed to 'c' at the and is concatination done.

to the question why ($c = 'c') is 'c'. This is a feature of php. it does 2 things at once. first it asigns the value to the variabe `$c` then if used in a expression the value of the variable `$c` is used.

Answer (score 0):

First it assign `'c'` to `$c` then concatenate it with `'d'` and finally echoes it. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

The order is: parenthesis and then outside. This is the same as:

```
$c = 'c';
$c = $c . 'd';
echo $c;
```

Comment: There is no second assignment to $c.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know, I just meant ato break up the expression in multiple instructions for a better understanding.